# Of how much use is a "relaxed" Content-Security-Policy

Tags: content-security-policy

The Guardian is (in my understanding) using a pretty relaxed Content-Security Policy:

```
default-src https:; script-src https: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src https: 'unsafe-inline'; img-src https: data: blob:; media-src https: data: blob:; font-src https: data:; connect-src https: wss:
```

Are there any advantages of using such a CSP as opposed to using none at all.

Answer (score 1):

Security wise, a relaxed one is still better than none.

In the above Guardian example, it disallows all http resources to be embedded.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jacob. The guardian is serving via https so at first I thought that all mixed content would be blocked by browsers anyway but this gave me some more information that not every type of mixed content is blocked: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/what-is-mixed-content

Comment: @Ronald I am not sure whether browser will block in the future, but right now it gave user an option to enable insecure contents. This is where CSP is more strict.